# How to enable https in elasticbeanstalk with multicontainer docker without using AWS 53 endpoint domain or any other domain's ssl?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I have elasticbeanstalk with multi-container with the following Dockerrun.json. And elb address `http://{app-name-env}.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/` , Now i wanted to convert `HTTP` to `HTTPS` without buying AWS 53 endpoints(any other cost-based purchase also). In some example, they are using HTTPS with {app-name-env}.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com as a domain.

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "containerDefinitions": [{
    "environment": [{
      "name": "POSTGRES_USER",
      "value": "admin"
    },
      {
        "name": "POSTGRES_PASSWORD",
        "value": "postgres"
      },
      {
        "name": "POSTGRES_DB",
        "value": "some-db"
      }
    ],
    "essential": true,
    "image": "postgres:12-alpine",
    "memory": 300,
    "mountPoints": [{
      "containerPath": "/var/lib/postgresql/data/",
      "sourceVolume": "postgres_data"
    }],
    "name": "db",
    "portMappings": [{
      "containerPort": 5432,
      "hostPort": 5432
    }]
  },
    {
      "essential": true,
      "links": [
        "db"
      ],
      "name": "web",
      "image": "**********.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/***:***",
      "memory": 300,
      "portMappings": [{
        "containerPort": 80,
        "hostPort": 80
      }]
    }
  ],
  "volumes": [{
    "host": {
      "sourcePath": "postgres_data"
    },
    "name": "postgres_data"
  }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What example? Do you have a link?

Comment: Here @Marcin https://medium.com/beck-et-al/elastic-beanstalk-made-simple-end-to-end-automation-with-cloudformation-f3f976309e56

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly you can't do this. For a valid public ssl certificate required for Https you **need your own domain**. You can't use aws provided domain for eb.

The tutorial you are following is using ACM for the ssl certificates which can only be obtained for your own domain.